# Translating a `for loop` into purrr using `map` function in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, tidyverse, purrr

I need to download weather data from NASA’s POWER (Prediction Of Worldwide Energy Resource). The package `nasapower` is a package developed for data retrieval using R. I need to download many locations (lat, long coordinates). To do this I tried a simple loop with three locations as a reproducible example.

```
library(nasapower)

data1 <- read.csv(text = "
location,long,lat
loc1, -56.547, -14.2427
loc2, -57.547, -15.2427
loc3, -58.547, -16.2427")

i=1
all.weather <- data.frame()
for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(data1))) {

        weather.data <- get_power(community = "AG",
                          lonlat = c(data1$long[i],data1$lat[i]),
                          dates = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-10"),
                          temporal_average = "DAILY",
                          pars = c("T2M_MAX"))
        
        all.weather <-rbind(all.weather, weather.data)
}
```

This works perfect. The problem is that I am trying to mimic this using `purrr::map` since I want to have an alternative within `tidyverse`. This is what I did but it does not work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

all.weather <- data1 %>%
    group_by(location) %>%
    map(get_power(community = "AG",
                lonlat = c(long, lat),
                dates = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-10"),
                temporal_average = "DAILY",
                site_elevation = NULL,
                pars = c("T2M_MAX")))
```

I got the following error:

```
Error in isFALSE(length(lonlat != 2)) : object 'long' not found
```

Any hint on how to run this using `purrr`?

Comment: is `get_power` compliant with _tidy eval_ ?  if not, you may have to specify data1$long, data1$lat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your code work make use of `purrr::pmap` instead of `map` like so:

1. `map` is for one argument functions, `map2` for two argument funs and `pmap` is the most general one allowing for funs with more than two arguments.
2. `pmap` will loop over the rows of your df. As your df has 3 columns 3 arguments are passed to the function, even if the first argument `location` is not used. To make this work and to make use of the column names you have to specify the function and the argument names via `function(location, long, lat)`

```r
library(nasapower)

data1 <- read.csv(text = "
location,long,lat
loc1, -56.547, -14.2427
loc2, -57.547, -15.2427
loc3, -58.547, -16.2427")

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

all.weather <- data1 %>%
  pmap(function(location, long, lat) get_power(community = "AG",
                                               lonlat = c(long, lat),
                                               dates = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-10"),
                                               temporal_average = "DAILY",
                                               site_elevation = NULL,
                                               pars = c("T2M_MAX"))) %>% 
  # Name list with locations
  setNames(data1$location) %>% 
  # Add location names as identifiers
  bind_rows(.id = "location")

head(all.weather)
#> NASA/POWER SRB/FLASHFlux/MERRA2/GEOS 5.12.4 (FP-IT) 0.5 x 0.5 Degree Daily Averaged Data  
#>  Dates (month/day/year): 01/01/2015 through 01/10/2015  
#>  Location: Latitude  -14.2427   Longitude -56.547  
#>  Elevation from MERRA-2: Average for 1/2x1/2 degree lat/lon region = 379.25 meters   Site = na  
#>  Climate zone: na (reference Briggs et al: http://www.energycodes.gov)  
#>  Value for missing model data cannot be computed or out of model availability range: NA  
#>  
#>  Parameters: 
#>  T2M_MAX MERRA2 1/2x1/2 Maximum Temperature at 2 Meters (C)  
#>  
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>   location   LON   LAT  YEAR    MM    DD   DOY YYYYMMDD   T2M_MAX
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <date>       <dbl>
#> 1 loc1     -56.5 -14.2  2015     1     1     1 2015-01-01    29.9
#> 2 loc1     -56.5 -14.2  2015     1     2     2 2015-01-02    30.1
#> 3 loc1     -56.5 -14.2  2015     1     3     3 2015-01-03    27.3
#> 4 loc1     -56.5 -14.2  2015     1     4     4 2015-01-04    28.7
#> 5 loc1     -56.5 -14.2  2015     1     5     5 2015-01-05    30  
#> 6 loc1     -56.5 -14.2  2015     1     6     6 2015-01-06    28.7
```

Comment: one question is why the location names from my df are not pulled in the output. Is there any way to conserve the location names in the output?

Comment: Hi @GiuseppePetri. I just made a small edit to my code to add a column with the location names to the final output

Comment: awesome! Thanks so much!